# How to really select a row in datagridview programatically not just highlight

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row, selection, highlight

I have this code to select  each row of `DataGridView` (by button click), but the associated controls don't display any data from the grid, only changes if i click manually at rows, this code only highlight the successive row but don't select really, the selection mark remains at the first row:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsUkj.jpg

```
 Dim i as integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If i > DataGridView.SelectedCells.Count - 1 Then
    Else
        _2018DataGridView.Rows(i).Selected = True
    End If
    i += 1
End Sub
```

The `DataGridView` settings:
multiselect = false

Other problem with this code: The highlighting only works until the visible rows. dont highlight if its no visible row.

Comment: Selection **IS** highlighting. If you want something else then it's not selecting that you want.  It sounds like what you want is to make a particular row the current row, i.e. the row containing the caret. To do that, you assign a cell in that row to the `CurrentCell` property of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! thats the problem, now works, solved with:

`For i = 0 To _2018DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
            _2018DataGridView.CurrentCell = _2018DataGridView.Item(0, i)`